# Drupal: How to make a list of nodes separated into sub sections with headers

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to make a page on Drupal 7 which should look this way:

[image: Showcase]

I am able to create:

- new content type
- new view
- nodes

But I don't know, how to set up the view. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is create one view page to display heading1 and node1, node2. And then create two blocks block1, block2. In block1 display heading2 and node3, node4 and in block2 display node5.

In the blocks section specify the blocks visibility only to one url which is of the view page you have created.

To limit the number of nodes and creating the offset you can use pager to display specific number of options.